# ghci gives ghc panic when using foreign c calls

Tags: haskell, linker, read-eval-print-loop, ffi, ghci

I'm trying to use ghci / `stack repl` on a project where one module has foreign calls linked to a C lib `tdsodbc`, but I keep getting

```
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.10.3 for x86_64-unknown-linux):
    Loading temp shared object failed: /tmp/ghc4628_0/libghc_71.so: undefined symbol: SQLPrepareW
```

(where `SQLPrepareW` is defined in that C lib). Building with stack works fine. This happens even on other modules that just happen to import the foreign-calling module, even without actually calling the foreign functions. It doesn't happen on load, but as soon as I try to fully evaluate any function in the repl.

How can I tell ghci that some of the functions are defined in libs outside of ghc?

I've tried the `-l` option (e.g. `stack exec ghci -- -ltdsodbc`), but the only difference then is that a different function from the same lib is in the error message:

```
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.10.3 for x86_64-unknown-linux):
        Loading temp shared object failed: /tmp/ghc24107_0/libghc_25.so: undefined symbol: SQLDriverConnectW
```

Note that it's obviously checking for the lib when using `-l`, since if I misspell it, it'll say it can't find it:

```
$ stack exec ghci -- -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc  -ltdsodbctypo
Warning (added by new or init): Specified resolver could not satisfy all dependencies. Some external packages have been added as dependencies.
You can suppress this message by removing it from stack.yaml

GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
<command line>: user specified .o/.so/.DLL could not be loaded (libtdsodbctypo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
Whilst trying to load:  (dynamic) tdsodbctypo
Additional directories searched:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc
```

This is with

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.4.0, Git revision e714f1dd3fade19496d91bd6a017e435a96a6bcd (4640 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.17.0
```

I've also tried `stack ghci --ghci-options '-ltdsodbc -fobject-code'`, but it also panics with `undefined symbol: SQLPrepareW`.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/448

Comment: ah, that looked so promising, I did earlier have some modules missing from `other-modules`, but even after adding and doing `stack clean && stack build && stack ghci` it still panics just as before :(

Comment: What does `nm libtdsodbc.so | grep SQLDriverConnectW` show?

Comment: `$ nm libtdsodbc.so␍
nm: libtdsodbc.so: no symbols` but `$ strings libtdsodbc.so|grep SQLDriverConnectW␍
SQLDriverConnectW` (and it compiles and runs fine with ghc, just not in ghci)

Comment: `strings` is not interesting, use `nm -D`.

Comment: `$ nm -D libtdsodbc.so|grep SQLDriverConnectW␍
0000000000012f20 T SQLDriverConnectW`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147358/discussion-between-unhammer-and-n-m).

Answer (score 0):

The nice folks in `#haskell` on freenode said maybe I should try passing `-fobject-code` to ghci. That didn't work. I tried `:set` and `:seti` to see if it was already set, but ghci didn't show anything about object code. (Doing `:unset -fobject-code` just gave `Some flags have not been recognized: -fno-object-code`.)

Then today I happened to look at my `~/.ghci` for some other reason, and that *did* have `:set -fobject-code`, even though `:set`/`:seti` doesn't show that. Removing `:set -fobject-code` from my `~/.ghci` took away the panic attacks, and I can now use functions from modules that import the module that defines foreign functions :)

Actually calling any of the foreign functions from ghci leads to a segfault ([catchsegv log](http://sprunge.us/TEFe) for the interested), but at least I can test the pure stuff now …